# Proctfile worker: node bot.js not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was setting up my discord bot, and I was trying change dynos from web to worker, but the worker isn't there.

My proctfile: "worker: node bot.js"

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're writing the dyno is right.
I think your problem is that you named the file `Proctfile`, while it should be `Procfile` (no t) instead.

Comment: still not working...
EDIT: Nervermind. Now it works. Thanks